# Clarifying the relation between Device Pixels & CSS pixels

Tags: html, css

This question presumes: device-pixels are absolute (fixed, not relative to anything).

Following reading this [article](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html),

1. My device (MacBook Pro 2019) has a pixel ratio of `2` (2 device pixels in every CSS pixel when zoom-level 100%; calculated by `.devicePixelRatio`). At 100% zoom-level, CSS pixels (as measured with `.innerWidth`) are the same as device pixels (as measured with `screen.width` & `Cmd + Shift + 4 + click`). I was expecting CSS pixels to be half the value of device pixels.
2. Why does MDN say CSS pixel is an absolute value when zooming in actually increases the size of a CSS pixel (by increasing the amount of device pixels it equals to)? Why is this in MDN?

[image]

Comment: How do you know "My device (MacBook Pro 2019) has a pixel ratio of 2"? At 100% zoom level, one device pixel equals one css pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the scaling is done at the OS level, so everything will "lie" because your OS is set to lie to every applications, including the browsers.

The `window.screen.width` value will be the one reported by your OS, but in your system preferences, it says that you want the resolution of your display to be set to half of its real resolution, that's what you'll get.

So even these values are not device pixels, but some kind of CSS pixels (well `window.screen.width` is really 'CSS pixels', the one from the *ScreenShot* app isn't).

However, while "lying" about the number of pixels, it correctly exposes the pixel density (number of physical pixel used per `px`). That's what you'll have in `window.devicePixelRatio` when the browser doesn't apply any zoom by itself.  Unfortunately, we don't know when the browser applies such a zoom, so as web-devs, we can't know the OS pixel density, nor the true resolution of the device.

---

As for the second point, I will assume you asked why MDN says *CSS pixels* are **absolute** rather than *relative* as written in your question.

This doesn't mean that a CSS pixel will always have the same physical dimension outputted <sub>(which is impossible btw, think of a video-projector)</sub>, it's in contrast with [relative lengths](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#relative-lengths) like `%`, `em`, `vw`, etc. which are relative to an other length.

CSS pixels are absolute in that they don't rely on any other length, even though the physical output may vary.

Comment: 1. what does the screenshot app measure? 2. Interesting point in how `devicePixelRatio` does change based on zoom but as developers have no way of knowing when a user zooms. This might explain my observation that web-developers don't really account for when a user zooms that much. The only thing I've seen is that you don't set `font-size` just in viewport dimension (like `vh` or `vw`) otherwise it'll never get bigger. 3. Okay, they don't vary based on any other length but do vary on zoom. I can accept that.

Comment: The screenshot app measures the OS px values, which are not CSS pixels because these are just relevant in the context of a web page that knows about CSS, but which are a very similar concept.

Comment: Okay, thanks. They're same as CSS pxs when 100% zoom. And they seem to represent device pixels (with OS' 'lie').